# Unable to see padding

Tags: c

I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct la {
  bool b;
  union {
    uint16_t i;
    struct {
      uint8_t j;
      uint8_t k;
    };
  };
} la_t;

int main()
{

    la_t a;
    a.b = 0x01c3;
    a.i = 0xa067;

    printf("%x", a.b);

    return 0;
}
```

I know that there is a padding after the bool of 1 byte and that the sizeof(la_t) is 4. However, even though I assign a 2 byte value to the bool, it only returns 01, the first byte. How can I access/see that padded byte with data?

Comment: you can't. It has been truncated already. You'd need to memcpy the value first, and then memcpy back to read it. Or write with an offset

Comment: `b` is not part of the union.

Comment: In general you can't access padding between members by accessing the member itself. You need to access the bytes of the struct directly using `char` pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's how a boolean type works. It's either true (`1`) or false (`0`).

The compiler will [implicitly convert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) all non-zero values to true, and zero to false already in the assignment to the boolean variable `b` (see the [boolean conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Boolean_conversion) section for the details).

---

And the only way to "see" the possible padding in a structure is to look at it in its raw binary form byte by byte. But note that padding while allowed it's still very much left as an implementation detail, and that the contents of possible padding bytes is indeterminate. Any attempt to read the data (or worse, write to it) is considered UB.

Comment: Attempting to read or write the padding bytes is not undefined behavior. Objects in C are composed of bytes (C 2018 6.2.6 2). You are explicitly permitted to read those bytes through pointers to character types (6.2.6 4 and 6.3.2.3 7). It is implied you can write them, as this is how `memcpy` is specified to work (7.24.2.1 2). The padding bytes do take on unspecified values when a structure member is modified (6.2.6 6).

Answer (score 0):

You can't legitimately access the padding — but you can demonstrate its presence by taking sizes and offsets into consideration.  Note that any non-zero value assigned to a `bool` results in the `bool` holding `1` aka `true`; only a zero value assigned will end up as `0` or `false`.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct la
{
    bool b;
    union
    {
        uint16_t i;
        struct
        {
            uint8_t j;
            uint8_t k;
        };
    };
} la_t;

int main(void)
{
    la_t a;
    a.b = 0x01c3;

    printf("%x\n", a.b);
    a.b = 0x0100;
    printf("%x\n", a.b);
    a.b = 0x0000;
    printf("%x\n", a.b);

    printf("Size   of a.b = %zu\n", sizeof(a.b));
    printf("Offset of a.b = %zu\n", offsetof(la_t, b));
    printf("Size   of a.i = %zu\n", sizeof(a.i));
    printf("Offset of a.i = %zu\n", offsetof(la_t, i));
    printf("Size   of a   = %zu\n", sizeof(a));

    return 0;
}
```

Output (from GCC 9.2.0 compiling on a MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave 10.14.6, with Xcode 11.3.1):

```
1
1
0
Size   of a.b = 1
Offset of a.b = 0
Size   of a.i = 2
Offset of a.i = 2
Size   of a   = 4
```

As you can see, there is 1 byte of unclaimed space (1 padding byte) between the boolean `b` and the anonymous union containing `i`.

You could copy the whole structure to an array of bytes (`memmove()` or `memcpy()`) and then inspect the byte value that was copied, but that is barely legitimate and may not be reliable.  Similarly in reverse, though the only way to see what's in the padding byte is by the copying mechanism once more.  Note that assignments to other members of the structure might or might not modify the padding byte.